# My Django Logger prints out a Memory Dump

Tags: python, django, logging

I am new to Django. I am using a simple logger but the out put is just 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
for about 10,000 lines. It was working and I can't work out what has changed. My settings.py has this for logging:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/myproj.logs'),
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format' : '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s',
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers':['file'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'DEBUG',
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers':['file'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'DEBUG',
    },
    'myapp': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

}

Comment: I'm still not sure why this is happening, but it appears that deleting the file get's it working again. SublimeText comes back with an error saying something like "can't represent all characters in Hex, using UTF-8." 

I'm not really sure how that happened but it appears to be working now; the only thing that changed is that I added the file to .gitignore.

Comment: What OS are you on? What does the code look like that is making the logging call?

Comment: I'm on Mac Yosemite but I'm running on an Ubuntu vagrant. The vagrant is running nginx and uWsgi in emperor mode. 
I think it might be something to do with either the vagrant or Sublime. The log file is perfectly fine after I've deleted it and restarted the app to recreate the file. Then, if I delete all the content in the file in Sublime, the next time anything gets written to the log it's in hex. I'm not actually printing anything to the log, but it's in debug mode so a lot of stuff gets written.